# How to do something when dom ready event?

Tags: jquery, events, live

I have ajax function that load content. And I want to do something when loaded content ready (loaded). How can i do that?

I try live():

```
$("ul.slide-gallery").live("ready", function(){
                $("ul.slide-gallery").prettyGallery();
            });
```

Not work.

Comment: You have two double quotes at the start of your jquery object.

Comment: That isn't possible.  You need to do it directly in the AJAX code.

Comment: @Vladimir: Why don't you post your AJAX code, so that someone can give you a solution that related directly to your problem?

Comment: What type of ajax call are you making? $.ajax, $.get, $.post??

Answer (score 2):

Use the ajax requests callback to do what you need to do. `Live` monitors events. Adding elements to the DOM is not an event so you can't do it that way. You never specified how you are making your ajax call so I will assume post.

```
$.post(url, function(data) {
      //load data or whatever you are doing
      //$('foo').append(data);

      //after loading call your code
      $("ul.slide-gallery").prettyGallery();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul.slide-gallery").prettyGallery();
});
```

Comment: How does this help with: *"I have ajax function that load content."*

Comment: Almost all jQuery should be wrapped in the document ready type of function. If you need to do something after using an $.ajax call, you can do it within its success method. Hope this helps! http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/